# Return names from a list when some letters match

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

How can I return an item from a list if a string matches part of the name?

```
nameList = ['hospital', 'Conference', 'schools']

string = 'confer'
match = any(string.lower() in name.lower() for name in nameList)
if match:
    # return 'Conference'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from difflib import get_close_matches

nameList = ['hospital', 'Conference', 'schools']

string = 'confer'

best_match = get_close_matches(string, nameList)
print(best_match)
```

Output:

```
['Conference']
```

You can check more about it here: [get_close_matches](https://www.kite.com/python/docs/difflib.get_close_matches)